# Cycle detection of a time series graph (y axis power) - machine productive cycle vs idle times

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I'm fairly new to data analysis so I'm not exactly sure on how to approach this problem. I have obtained data output from an industrial machine which has 2 states - productive and idle. The productive cycle of the machine is a regular pattern occurring inbetween the idle states, which vary in length of times.

The productive cycle is distinct, however not identical in terms of the peaks and troughs of the power consumption. Lets assume the cycle time length can also vary.

I need to figure out a way to identify the productive cycle length based on this data, in order to provide meaningful statistics such as if the productive cycle length has been increasing over time (due to the machinary being less efficient). How would I best approach this problem?

I'm currently using PHP for the backend of my system, however I'm open to using Python for the data analysis since it appears to be the go to choice for these type of problems.